# PDF controls not working in Chrome PDF viewer (but do in IE and Firefox)

Tags: pdf-reader

[This PDF](http://www.orsgroup.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/PHaMs-Referral-Form.pdf) will open within the browser in Internet Explorer, Chrome and Firefox.

In IE, the PDF's controls at the bottom of the page (Print/Save/Email) will work fine.

[image]

However, those controls will not work when the PDF is viewed inside Chrome.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You probably know this, but the controls for chrome's built-in pdf reader are on the top of the screen, on an autohide drop-down bar. You have to mouse hover over the top 1/2" of the pdf to get it to appear. In the image, the controls are in the top right. Is this toolbar not appearing at all, doesn't have any buttons on it, are they there but clicking does nothin, or are you not using the chrome built-in viewer and have a different one (adobe, foxit, etc.)?
[image: Screenshot of Chrome Built-in pdf viewer]

Update after clarification - It turns out that chrome has little support for Javascript or other active content embedded in pdf documents. There is a bug related to it https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=495549 but in general it appears that they are in no hurry to change this. The general advice on the chrome forums is to disable the chrome pdf viewer and use a third party viewer plugin instead (i.e. adobe).

Comment: Thanks Argonauts, I forgot to specify: I meant the controls built into the PDF document, please see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the iFrame have set height:200px, very little, then the iFrame block the PDF Viewer Toolbar in Chrome (It worked fine in IE and Firefox). 
Then, the solution was I change to 600px and works!

```
<iframe id="miframe" src="...." frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" style="height:600px;width:100%"></iframe>
```